# How to go to particular section without scrolling behavior / Any alternative to scrollIntoView() without scroll behavior?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, redirect

I am trying to create a page redirection to a particular section, i.e. I want to go to a particular anchor div on a page without scrolling behavior. However, I have a query string in the URL for pagination so the #id method failed for me. I tried "scrollIntoView()" but it contains the page scrolling behavior, which is undesired. May I ask if there is any alternative solution to this problem?

I am using Vue for the frontend & Codeigniter for the backend. Here is my code:

```
        mounted() {
            // anchorPageToProductList
            if (this.isOnQuery) {
                console.log('isOnQuery');
                this.scrollToProductList();
            } else {
                console.log('isNotOnQuery');
            }
            
        },
```

```
methods: {
   scrollToProductList(){
       window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       // scroll animation
       document.getElementById('product-list-anchor').scrollIntoView(true);
     });
},
```

Example of my URL case:

```
http://www.example.com/Product/list?search=&sort=3&type=-1&event%5B%5D=11&pagination=1
```

Thank you!!

Comment: If you do not want to scroll, then you need to copy the content into a container in the viewport I would think

Comment: You can unset the scrolling behavior, then scroll, then reset your scrolling behavior to the initial value

Comment: You should be able to use the #id URL method. For the correct order see: [anatomy of a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#basics_anatomy_of_a_url). How's your headache now?

Comment: Query string cannot affect how hash anchors work. What did you try exactly?

Comment: lol, thanks for all the comments trying to relieve my headache xD

Comment: Because I have html {scroll-behavior: smooth} in my css for the back to top button so it will have the scrolling behavior xD.    My headache is now getting better and I'll post my solution below. Stackoverflow is a good place for relieving headache :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to unset the scrolling behavior, allow the the page to jump to the desired section, then set back the smooth-scroll behavior. So It now works without the scrolling behavior. Thanks for all the comments:)

My code:

```
scrollToProductList(){

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      // select the whole html & disable smooth-scroll behavior in css
      let htmlElement = document.querySelector('html');
      htmlElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'auto';

      // go to the anchor point
      document.getElementById('product-list-anchor').scrollIntoView(true);

      // enable smooth-scroll behavior again
      htmlElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth';

  });

}
```